# jQuery append() not working on certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append

The website I'm creating is http://www.industrialmerchants.com

The problem portion of my script is the following:

```
var collapseAll = document.createElement('img');
    collapseAll.src = collapseAllSrc;
    collapseAll.className = "collapseAll";
    collapseAll.style.cssFloat = "right";

    imUI(".menuBrowser .sideModuleHeader").append(collapseAll);
```

(imUI is the noConflict variable I'm using. If you are wondering why I use this verbose method of creating a DOM element, it is because this was my last ditch effort to get this code to work.)

For some bizarre reason, nothing is appended to the selected div. The div is definitely being selected because the length property is returning 1. To make things even more confusing, I have another "module" with a nearly identical DOM structure. When I alter the selector to include the .sideModuleHeader div from both modules, the image is inserted in the second module but not the first. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that it's being appended but is not visible?

Comment: does using appendTo have the same result?

Comment: No. It doesn't show up in the DOM when I inspect the div with firebug.

Comment: Just inverted the expression to use appendTo(). Same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does get added, but a few lines later you have:

```
toggleButtons = imUI(".menuBrowser img").remove(".collapseAll")...
```

which then immediately deletes it.

Comment: Oh fudge! I thought remove() removes an element from the jQuery selection, not from the DOM. Thanks!

Comment: The not() function is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are mixing core javascript with jquery.
try:

```
var collapseAll = $('<img />').attr('src',collapseAllSrc).addClass("collapseAll");
collapseAll.css({'float':'right'})
```

-edit: i had a ':' instead of a ',' on the attr part.

Answer (score -2):

Try with append Child:

```
 imUI(".menuBrowser .sideModuleHeader").appendChild(collapseAll);
```

Comment: appendChild() is not a valid jQuery function.